# Why is Chr function not returning result in the Immediate window

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I expected `?Chr(65)` to return `A` in the immediate window but I get the following:

[image]

In `Excel-VBA`s immediate window it does what I'd expect:

[image]

How do I amend the code in the VB immediate window so it returns `A` ?

Comment: Are you not missing a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, and does your project list `Microsoft.VisualBasic` as implicitly imported for all code modules?

Comment: sounds like that would solve it but it hasn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `?System.Convert.ToChar(65)` or `?Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(65)`

Comment: well yes that works but I'm wanting to see the result of the functions either `Chr` or `ChrW` rather than `Char` ....

Comment: Can you try to use `?Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(65)`? Will It cause an error? Both of methods are working for me